# Not able to inspect element in IOS webview on real devices

Tags: ios, appium

I am using `appium 1.8.0` with and launching `webview` from my app. For that `webview`  In `IOS` I am not able to get the page source and not able to do any operation.

The same thing is working on android. 
Do I have to do any steps to enable the `IOS` `webview` to get the page source?

Comment: To get the page source for a webview, you have to view the page in a regular browser.

Comment: For automating ios webviews you need to use ios_webkit_debug_proxy. Google about it. And for inspecting the elements you have to use Mac Safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion could be to use something you are already familiar i.e. chrome dev tools which you have used for android webview inspection, same thing can be used for ios webview also

Install node module

```
npm install remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter -g
```

Start the adapter at port 9000 - This will auto start "ios-webkit-debug-proxy" (Make sure this should be installed as a prerequisite on mac machine)

```
remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter --port=9000
```

Open chrome and navigate to chrome://inspect and iOS targets will show up

More details [here](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter#getting-started) on the tools github readme file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . with above steps i am able to find the elements and able to write the code. but when i run the test using appium it fails as it does not detect the web view element. Can you please suggest what could be the best way to enable the web view using appium . i know there was bug in earlier appium version (1.7) where for iOS web view elements are not detected . but it should have been fixed in later versions . What could be the best approach